# Magento 2.2.0 How to attach multiple files using Rest api with large size of file?

Tags: rest-api, magento2.2.0

**Magento 2.2.0** How to attach multiple files using **Rest API** with large size of file?

> code is below for attach png file using webservices :

```
$data='data:application/pdf;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAHgAAAB4CAMAAAAOusbgAAAAFVBMVEUA/wCt/67q4eHo4t6p/6rc2dDc/93m3krJAAAAZElEQVRoge3bQQHAMAzEsDRJyx/yWOw+MgEhcN3pQHNr3p7f2zfVW4G2q08CPmAwGAwGg8FgMBgMBoPBYDAYDAaDwWAwGAwGg8FgMBgMBoPBYDAYDAaDwWAwGAzOrWWxmS61D36npAXNP8b4QQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==';//$singlefile['content'];
            //return $data."----".$singlefile['content'];
            $source = fopen($data, 'r');
            $destination = fopen('/var/www/html/xfactory-magento/pub/media/catalog/product/i/p/'.$singlefile['name'], 'w');
            stream_copy_to_stream($source, $destination);
            fclose($source);
            fclose($destination);
```